# if you're a federal employee and you quit during the shutdown will you still get backpay?

Tags: united-states, employment, government

Right now there are 800,000 or so furloughed federal employees that aren't being paid. Many of these employees are being forced to continue working despite not having received a paycheck.

My question is...  if I, as a federal employee, were to leave my job and go into the private sector, would I still be getting backpay when the government re-opens?

Comment: If you worked you're owed pay.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about those who were forced to work during the shutdown? or those who were not forced to work during the shutdown?

Comment: @user102008 - people who were forced to work during the shutdown.

Comment: @quid That assumption does not hold with respect to the shutdown. Recent legislation has made it true, but the matter was undecided until the legislation was passed: https://www.federaltimes.com/management/pay-benefits/2019/01/11/congress-passes-federal-pay-guarantee-after-shutdown/

Comment: Ya, I beg to differ. There are boatloads of employment law in the US, there is no way the federal government would have gotten away from the extremely inevitable class action suit (nevermind the mutiny) that would have resulted from stiffing employees out of worked hours.  As far as I'm concerned that was a largely empty gesture to calm heads now that a paycheck has been actually missed.  I dare your employer to decide to simply not count some hours you worked because the accounting office was closed.  The matter was not undecided before, but it is double decided now.